# ¿Cómo añadir una libreria con muchos .jar, como iText?

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito importar `iText` y el paquete que me descargo está repleto de `.jar` . Yo sé importar uno a uno, pero supongo que debo importarlos a la vez. Por más que busco no encuentro ningún caso como este.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a intentar explicarlo de la mejor forma posibles:

**1º Crear la librería:**

- Click derecho sobre el proyecto ->
- Properties ->
- Jaba Build Path ->
- (Pestaña) Libraries ->
- (Botón) Add Library... ->
- (Opción de tabla) User Library ->
- (Botón) Next > ->
- (Botón) User Libarires ... ->
- (Botón) New ... -> Introduces el nombre de tu librería personalizada.

**2º Añadir elementos a la librería**

Haces `click` sobre esa librería y le das a `Add Jars...` En esa ventana seleccionas los jar que quieras añadir a tu librería personalziada.

**3º Añadir la librería editada a tu poryecto**

Cierras la edición de librerías de usuario.

Vuelves de nuevo la ventana de librerías de usuario y haces click sobre la librería personalizada que acabas de crear y le das a finalizar.

Tu librería se habrá añadido a tu proyecto.